# comparing images pixel by pixel

Tags: matlab, opencv

I am working on some images. I am given an `abc.tif` image ( color image) . I read it as follows:

```
Mat test_image=imread("abc.tif",IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

I perform some operations on it and convert it into some binary image (using threshold) containing only two values 0 and 255 which are stored in img image where img is created as following:

```
Mat img(584,565,CV_8UC1);   %//(so now img contains only 0 and 255)
```

I save this image using `imwrite("myimage.jpg",img);`

I want to compare the `myimage.jpg` image with another binary image `manual.gif` pixel by pixel to check whether one image is duplicate of another but as you can notice the problem is OpenCv doesnot support .gif format so I need to convert it into .jpg and because of that the image changes and now both the images will be concluded as different images may be even though they are same. What to do now?

Actually I am working on retinal blood vessel segmentation and these images are found in the DRIVE database.

I am given these images. Original image:

[image]

I perform some operations on it and extract blood vessels from it and then create a binary image and store in some Mat variable img as discussed earlier. Now I have got another image (.gif image) which I cannot load as shown below:

[image]

Now I want to compare my img image (binary) with the  given .gif image (above) which I cannot load.

Comment: Just convert your GIF to PNG using an external tool like IrfanView and OpenCV will read it. Also, don't save your results as JPG as that is a lossy format that will change your values. Save it as a lossless PNG as well.

Comment: Or use ImageMagick, where the command is as simple as `convert input.gif output.png`

Comment: Thank You for your valuable inputs!!

Comment: Cool problem! Is it for authentication? How similar are those nets concerning the number of branches?

Comment: Yes its kind of authentication . 80-85% similar.

Comment: @Navdeep Accept an answer if it's correct. If not, specify what's wrong so others can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use ImageMagic for converting your .gif to .PNG in batch mode. You could also convert it on the fly using `system("convert img.gif img.png")` call.

I'm not sure, if pixel comparison will give you good result. An offset shift of the same image will result in bad match.
**EDIT** As an idea. Maybe calculating centers of gravity and shifting/rotating both images to have the same origin may help here.

Consider using moments, freeman chain or other mode robust shape comparison methods.

Answer (score 0):

first off you will want to use the images in the same format as each other @Adi mentioned jpg is lossy in the comments which is correct so shouldn't be used until possibly after any work is done. [MATLAB - image conversion](https://machinelearning1.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/convert-image-in-matlab-bmp-gif-hdf-jpg-jpeg-jp2-jpx-pbm-pgm-ppm-pnm-pcx-png-ras-tif-tiff-xwd/)

you will also want the images to be of the same size. you can compare them using the size function and then pad them to add pixels to make the dimensions the same. the padding can always be removed later, just watch how the padding is added so as not to affect your operations.

you will also need to look into rotations, consider putting the image into the frequency domain and rotate the image to align the spectrum's.

below is a simple pixel comparison code, pixel comparison is not particularly accurate for comparing. even the slightest miss alignment will cause false negatives or false positives.

```
%read image
test_image1 = imread('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg');
test_image2 = imread('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg');

%convert to gray scale
gray_img1 = rgb2gray(test_image1);
gray_img2 = rgb2gray(test_image2);

% threshold image to put all values greater than 125 to 255 and all values
% below 125 to 0
binary_image1 = gray_img1 > 125;
binary_image2 = gray_img2 > 125;

%binary image to size to allow pixel by pixel checking
[row, col] = size(binary_image1);

% initialize the counters for similar and different pixelse to zero
similar = 0;
different = 0;

%two loops to scan through all rows and columns of the image. 
for kk = 1 : row
    for yy = 1 : col
        %using if statement with isequal function to compare corresponding
        %pixel values and count them depending ont he logical output of 
        %isequal 
        if isequal(binary_image1(kk,yy), binary_image2(kk,yy))
           similar = similar + 1;
        else
            different = different + 1;
        end
    end
end

% calculate the percentage difference between the images and print it
total_pixels = row*col;
difference_percentage = (different / total_pixels) * 100;
fprintf('%f%% difference between the compared images \n%d pixels being different to %d total pixels\n', difference_percentage, different, total_pixels )

% simple supbtraction of the two images
diff_image = binary_image1 - binary_image2;


%generate figure to show the original gray and corresponding binary images
%as well as the subtraction
figure
subplot(2,3,1)
imshow(gray_img1);
title('gray img1');

subplot(2,3,2)
imshow(gray_img2);
title('gray img2');

subplot(2,3,4)
imshow(binary_image1);
title('binary image1');

subplot(2,3,5)
imshow(binary_image2);
title('binary image2');

subplot(2,3,[3,6])
imshow(diff_image);
title('diff image');
```